# android studio 3.1 DDMS is deprecated - how to send sms and mock locations etc to emulator now?

Tags: android, ddms

DDMS has been deprecated.   i need a way to be able to test sending sms and phone calls and call waitings, etc using the emulator. DDMS was very useful for this. i can probably run DDMS outside android studio but my question is if its deprecated it means there is a better way ? so what is the better way to test these things ?

I tried looking in tools menu but its not there.  To be clear, i am searching for a way to sending mock locations, sms, and phone calls events to the emulator

The other issue is when i send sms using ddms (that i opened via command line) its not working. im using api 27 which comes with android messages new app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i was reading from the android docs the reason ddms is gone is because the tools are already inside android studio. but i did not know where. when i opened an emulator i finally found most of the ddms tools . i'll show you a screenshot of where to look:

[image]

[image]